# How to replace <datatable> tag by <table> tag

Tags: java, html, jsf, datatable

I am working on a web application and I have to convert a HTML page (have multiple tables and icons) to PDF. I want to replace `h:dataTable` tag in JSP to simple `table` tag in HTML. So this is how current table looks like

```
<h:dataTable value="#{entry.value}" var="tableRow"
rendered="#{not empty entry.value}" styleClass="employeeTable"
headerClass="employeeTableHeader"
rowClasses="employeeTableOddRow,employeeTableEvenRow">
                                     <h:column>
                                            <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
                                            <h:outputText size="10" value="#{tableRow.name}" />
                                     </h:column>

                                     <h:column>
                                            <f:facet name="header">State</f:facet>
                                            <h:outputText size="8" value="#{tableRow.state}" />
                                     </h:column>

                                     <h:column>
                                            <f:facet name="header">Language</f:facet>
                                            <h:outputText size="8" value="#{tableRow.language}" />
                                     </h:column>
```

I want to convert this table into simple HTML table like this

```
<table>
   <tr>                                          
  <th id="Nm">Name</th>
  <th id="St">State</th>
  <th id="Lang">Language</th>
   </tr>
 <tr>
  <td >  <h:outputText  value="#{tableRow.name}" /></td>
  <td >  <h:outputText  value="#{tableRow.state}" /></td>
   <td >  <h:outputText value="#{tableRow.language}" /></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

I tried this but I am not able to retrieve any value from java layer. I am trying to this because I have to create a `PDF Document` which contains this table and I am using `jsPDF` to do this. And jsPDF can take the content only from simple `<table> tag`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the document is still in a format 'xml' you can open it as xml document precisely. You can do it if you want to work it in jquery client-side or server-side in a language like PHP (or any other server-side language) that allows the manipulation of XML documents. Using this component, you can scan the original document and edit it or create a new one that has the features that you need following the trail of the original document ..